# PDF to Text Conversion - Multiple Lines in Next Page

Tags: c#, itext

My PDF content is as follows:

First page:

```
Date          Item                     IN          OUT       
17-Oct        Electrical Fan           -           38        
              with RF895 cable
              model XO-8745
              56148
       
17-Oct        Electrical Iron           77          -      
              with ring
              model X12358
              78418
              newline 
:
:
:
17-Oct        Electrical Fan            77          -    

    Note: This receipt is computer generated and no signature is required
```

Second page:

```
Date          Item                     IN          OUT               
              with RF895 cable
              model XO-8745
              56148

17-Oct        Electrical Iron           -          100      
              with ring
              model 54789

              XP-859
              newline 
:
:
:
17-Oct        Electrical Iron           17          -      
              with ring
              
    Note: This receipt is computer generated and no signature is required
```

Third page:

```
Date          Item                     IN          OUT       
              model X12358
              56148
   
17-Oct        Electrical Fan           -           38        
              with RF895 cable
              model XO-8745
              56148
:
:
:
17-Oct        Electrical Fan           108          -        
              with RF895 cable
              model XO-8745
              56148


    Note: This receipt is computer generated and no signature is required
```

I used Itextsharp to join the data into 1 line and put it into excel, since the second line is in next page, i couldn't get the line i wanted because it only read PDF page by page.
codes as follow:

```cs
if (File.Exists(theFile.FullName))
{
    Console.Write(++count + " " + theFile.FullName);
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(theFile.FullName);
    try
    {
        DataTable finalTbl = GetTable();
        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy); //Convert to text from PDF
            string[] theLines = currentText.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(currentText))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] splittedTxt = line.Split(new[] { " " },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    if (splittedTxt.Any())
                    {
                        // create a table
                    }
                    finalTbl.Rows.Add( //add desired datatable)
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
    catch
   {
   throw;
      }
      finally
  {
   pdfReader.Close();
  }
}
```

Result i get:

```
17-Oct        Electrical Fan with RF895 cable model XO-8745 56148
17-Oct        Electrical Iron with ring model X12358 78418 newline 
17-Oct        Electrical Fan 
17-Oct        Electrical Iron with ring model 54789  XP-859 newline 
17-Oct        Electrical Iron with ring
17-Oct        Electrical Fan with RF895 cable model XO-8745 56148
17-Oct        Electrical Iron with ring model X12358
17-Oct        Electrical Fan with RF895 cable model XO-8745 56148
17-Oct        Electrical Fan with RF895 cable model XO-8745 56148
```

is there any how to read and merged all page first before i create a data table?

Comment: Pdf are not really good datasource. You are lucky to get Text out of it. And in the right order. Here you have a Date that is only on the first line. Perhaps you can insert only when a new date is found or the document is finished.

Comment: @DragandDrop - At least they're not screen scraping!

Comment: How about concatenating the `currentText` values of all the pages to a single large string and eventually analyzing that big string?